# Get weather for specific date using Openweather API - parsing JSON response for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

So far I have this and it works well for the current day, but how can I get data for a specific date and time?

```js
fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q='+qalaqi+'&appid=b0454686b4c0f5459fed65be7ad96ae7')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

This is how I assign specific values to variables

```
  var tempValue = data['main']['temp'];
  var descValue = data['weather'][0]['description'];
  var cnevaValue = data['main']['pressure'];
  var tenianobaValue = data['main']['humidity'];
  var qariValue = data['wind']['speed'];
  var xilvadobaValue = data['visibility'];
  var iconamindiValue = data['weather'][0]['icon'];
```

I just can't figure how to get a specific date value for a specific hour, there should be some sort of filter or something. API itself provides a full list of the following five days, but sadly I have no idea how to display specific date data and specific hour

I have added screenshot -

[image]

Comment: https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=tbilisi&appid=b0454686b4c0f5459fed65be7ad96ae7

Comment: you may use   "dt_txt" property of the data for filtering data based on the date and time.

Comment: That is my problem, I can't find a suitable filter for this :(

Comment: just create an object with dt_txt and store the value corresponding to it.

Comment: Like this? ```var matchingResults = data.filter(function(x){ return x.dt_txt == "2020-09-16 18:00:00"; });``` it wont work

Comment: What I am trying to do is to filter on children level, return the parent of specific ['list']['listnumberhere']